# Getting error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheet_name' when passing sheet_name argument to read_excel in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Running this in a jupyter notebook with this. When I run it with just the file path it works fine but when I try to specify a sheet it gives me the error. What would be the right syntax to make this parameter (and I guess other parameters) work?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(the file path's name would be here), sheet_name='the sheets name'
                 )
df
```

Comment: remove the `pd.DataFrame` wrapping the read_excel, that's not needed

Comment: what version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: The correct syntax is `pd.read_excel("filepath", sheet_name="the sheet I want")`. Run `help(pd.read_excel)` in an interactive session for more info, or the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Like Yuca said in the comments. You need to remove the `pd.DataFrame`

your code should be like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('C:/path/to/file.xlsx', sheet_name='the sheets name')
```